# Assert that all properties but some are null

Tags: .net, unit-testing, testing, .net-core, nunit

I have mapping methods, that maps model `A` to model `B`. I write unit tests for all of there. I want to somehow nicely handle situation when destination model has a lot of properties, but most of them are `null`. The test purpose is to test that some small number of properties were correctly mapped and others were not mapped at all (no other than designed properties were set) without having to specify every property.

I cannot change the `B` class because it is usually service contract that I am calling with only few properties out of many.

Can you please help how to simplify the unit test?

I am using .NET Core 2.1 and NUnit.

Example of current state:

```
public class B
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public string Prop4 { get; set; }
    public string Prop5 { get; set; }
    // a lot of other properties
}
```

Mapping method:

```
public B Map(A a)
{
    return new B
    {
        Id = a.Id // only Id property is set
    };
}
```

Test:

```
[Test]
public void MapTest()
{
    var a = new A { Id = "123" };
    var b = mapping.Map(a);

    Assert.That(b, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(b.Id, Is.EqualTo(a.Id));

    Assert.That(b.Prop1, Is.Null); // this is what i want to simplify
    Assert.That(b.Prop2, Is.Null);
    Assert.That(b.Prop3, Is.Null);
    Assert.That(b.Prop4, Is.Null);
    Assert.That(b.Prop5, Is.Null);
    // a lot of other properties
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, the only option I see is using`Reflection` but I'd argue that this does not really simplify your code

Comment: I had that idea, but as you say, that's not the type of solution that I am looking for.

Comment: Are you sure that all properties of `B` class are static?

Comment: @Fabio, thanks, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

[FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/documentation/#object-graph-comparison) framework have feature to assert whole object.
Create expected instance and assert it against actual result of map method.

```
[Test]
public void MapTest()
{
    var a = new A 
    { 
        Id = "123",
        Name = "Name of A",
        SomeProperty = new LowLevelClass { Value = 42 } 
    }; 
    var expected = new B 
    { 
        Id = "123"
    };

    var actual = mapping.Map(a);

    actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
}
```

Sample above assumes, that default constructor of `B` do not instantiate other properties, but if it does, than you will create expected instance of `B` and explicilty set other properties to `null`

```
var expected = new B 
{ 
    Id = "123",
    Name = null,
    SomeProperty = null
};

var actual = mapping.Map(a);

actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
```

Comment: I don't believe this solves the problem as stated, since the mapping function is not mapping all the properties.

Comment: @Charlie, I created `expected` instance where other properties are `null`. So `actual` result should have them `null` as well. Of course in my sample I assume that default constructor of `B` do not instantiate other properties.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say that there is no way to do this in NUnit's native assertions. You could encapsulate the logic in a method that takes a list of property names and uses reflection. That's how I've done it in similar cases.

A neat way to package the logic would be to write

```
Assert.That(b, Has.Properties("Prop1", "Prop2", ...).Null;
```

where Has.Properties would replace the argument b with a list of all the named property values and then apply the following constraint to it.

This doesn't seem general enough to include in NUnit itself but is doable as custom constraint.

Another way to do it would be to write

```
Assert.That(b.Properties("Prop1", "Prop2"...), Is.All.Null);
```

where Properties is an extension method for `object`.

A third option (maybe the easiest) would be to extend NUnit's `ListMapper`.